# Can't locate my raw folder (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, directory

First of all, I'm a noob, I just started coding and I don't know much about it.

My problem is that I want to create a MediaPlayer that plays a sound I've placed in a `raw` folder inside the `res` folder in my project. But when I do

```
example = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.myfile)
```

it doesn't locate the `R.raw*` path.

I can solve this by importing `android.R` in my class, but now it won't locate my classes.

This is when I try without importing `android.R`

And this when I import `android.R`

Also it won't locate my file inside the `raw` folder either way.

Pls help I can't get it to work :c

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your project.

To do that you can go on the Build > Rebuild Project.

Comment: Already solved it! i just reseted Android studio and it started working :O